# SCRIPT5009: 'offsetParent' is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#

i'm trying to introduce my app in web. It works perfectly in test area. But when i carry it to prod area it gives this fault. Is there anyone who faced with this problem before ?

[image]

Comment: Does this work on other browsers

Comment: Hello, no i tried it on Chrome. But it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Well it says "'offsetParent' is undefined", the error message is self-explanatory, but we have to see more of your code to see why it's giving that error.

Comment: @gcampbell it's not even located in my code. When i search for ananymous() function or offsetParent.clientWidth parts, there is no search result. Probably web browser generates this function and takes fault message. This part is not written by me.

Comment: What versions of Internet Explorer are you using in your Test area and Production area?

Comment: @TomTrumper i solved the problem by the way. It's all about cash. To clear the cash i pressed CTRL and F5. Then the problem solved.